# How to Solve $y=(x^\lambda-1)/\lambda$ for $\lambda$ given $x$ and $y$?

Tags: real-analysis

Solve $y=(x^\lambda-1)/\lambda$ for $\lambda$ given $x$ and $y$.

$x$, $y$, and $\lambda$ are all real numbers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You equation is equivalent to $\lambda y = x^\lambda - 1$, for $\lambda \neq 0$, and to $\lambda y + 1= \exp\{\lambda \ln x\}$ for $\lambda \neq 0$. This is a transcendental equation that has no closed-form solution. You will have to rely on an algorithm like the Newton method to find a numerical solution.

The solution is usually represented in term of the Lambert W Function. If you'd like to read more on this special function, see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambert_W_function.

Comment: Thanks, \lambda=-1/y-1/\log x W(-\log x/y \exp(-\log x/y))